# How to get keyboard input in an Homemade OS?

Tags: c++, operating-system

How to get keyboard input in an Homemade OS?

Comment: Isn't that for you to define?

Comment: Exactly. There is no set in stone answer, it depends on how you've already coded it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that no further explanations are given, I'll assume a x86 platform.

You need to install a handler for the keyboard interrupt. Here is an example as a Linux module that you can probably get inspiration from: http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x1210.html

And also:

http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupts

If you give more detail about your OS (architecture? real or protected mode?) we can probably give you better answers.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this: http://wiki.osdev.org/PS2_Keyboard.

Comment: ...now ain't that a lucky answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just like the rest of your hardware, you will need to write a device driver (or modify an existing one). If your hardware is the same as for some other o/s you will probably be lucky.

Btw, it can be a good idea to have all drivers present the same interface, say a virtual serial port.

If you are really, really stuck you will have to contact the manufacturer of some devices.